# API - Any Way to validate Playlist IDs?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, conditional-statements, playlist

Here's my problem. The website I am working on has a slew of different products that could possibly have a link to a YouTube Video or Playlist. I have been requested to embed that link on the page instead of sending the end-user away from the page to view the video/playlist. Easy enough.

I'm using a JSTL fn.substring and fn.substringAfter to isolate the VideoID and PlaylistID of each URL that is imported into the page

```
<c:if test="${hyperlink.type.name eq 'YouTubeLinking'}">
<c:set var="videoSub" value="${fn:substringAfter(hyperlink.link, 'watch?v=')}"/>
<c:set var="videoID" value="${fn:substring(videoSub, 0, 11)}"/>
<c:set var="playlistSub" value="${fn:substringAfter(hyperlink.link, 'list=')}"/>
<c:set var="playlistID" value="${fn:substring(playlistSub, 0, 34)}"/>
```

I am then using a simple IF conditional to look at the PlaylistID, and if it its empty, then just employ the single video embed.

```
<c:if test="${empty playlistID}">
<iframe width="540" height="304" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<c:out value="${videoID}"/>?rel=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${not empty playlistID}">
<iframe width="540" height="304" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=<c:out value="${playlistID}"/>" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</c:if>
```

The problem is... A lot of these Playlists are no longer valid, meaning the playlist has been deleted. We're talking thousands of products that could potentially link to hundreds of playlists.

Is there anyway that I can use the YouTube API to check to see if the PlayListID is valid (will not return a 400 error), and if it is not valid, then just employ the single video embed markup?

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of Video Link Checker plugin. Here is what I recommend you do:

1) Make an API call for [playlistItems](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) with the playlist ID.

2) If the API returns an empty result, the playlist has been deleted. Otherwise,

3) Has the playlist->status->privacyStatus been changed and no longer public? (not uncommon)

4) Is the playlist->contentDetails->itemCount > 0? Sometimes the playlist owner removes all the videos but leaves the playlist active.

5) Are there playlist->contentDetails->regionRestrictions? Check vs target region to see if the embedded video will even play.

Answer (score 0):

Call Youtube Data API's [Playlists: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list) which returns all of a channel's playlist. Pass `snippet` as `part` parameter as it returns info like `title` and `id`. Compare the response to what you have. That way you'll know if a Playlist still exists.